# How to convert numbers with related bases quickly?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, boolean-algebra, binary

Let:

$a = (1011011)_2 = (1123)_4$

There two ways to solve it:

1. Convert the number in base 2 to base 10 then to base $4$.
2. Consider $4 = 2^2$ and group each of two numbers in base $2$ to one in base $4$.

I can easily convert when the source base in less than then destiny base but how could I do the inverse?

Said:

$b = (1123)_4 = (x)_2$

I tried to do successive divisions grouping each two numbers in base $4$ as the source base is greater than destiny but I get different results, that can be seen:

$(1123)_4 = (11)_4 (23)_4$

$(11)_4 \Rightarrow (1011)_2$

$(23)_4 \Rightarrow (10111)_2$

$(1123)_4 \nRightarrow (1011 10111)_2$

I am doing the successive divisions correctly but it seems I am getting one bit more than expected.

How to correctly do this?

[image]

Comment: Weird, I redid the division for 23 in base 4 directly to base 2 and I get different results.

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty I see, so I convert 5 to base 2 and keep dividing? I thought this kind of rule applied and made the conversion faster. It seems I need to convert to base 10 then back to the destiny base anyway.

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think each single digit in base 4 corresponds to 2 digits in base 2 (possibly 0-filled):

$$(1123)_4 = (\underbrace{01}_1 \underbrace{01}_1 \underbrace{10}_2 \underbrace{11}_3)_2$$

One usually omits leading zeroes in the final result, so you have $(1011011)_2$.

Comment: So for example. If I have (234)8 = (x)2 then each single digit on base 8 is 3 digits in 2? So if I have a base s, d related and s > r then the every single digit in s equals to the power of r?

Comment: @0vid: Yes. Each digit in base $b^n$ corresponds to $n$ digits in base $b$.